# Is there a way to browse only the "Portrait mode" images with depth information through imagePickerController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to develop an app which utilises depth information embedded within "Portrait Mode" images. Is there a way that I can give the user provision to only select the "Portrait Mode" images through the imagePickerController class?

Comment: Have you found the answer?)